# Raspberry PI Access Point is not viewable on any device

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am working to setup RPI 3 model B as a standalone Access point as specified in this [article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md). After i followed all instructions, and rebooted the RPI, The AP is not accessible or viewable on my iPhone or PC so i can connect through the wifi.

I am implementing this on a with latest raspbian stretch image (March version).

Let me know what i am missing so i can see the AP wifi network i set on the RPI device.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue and it looks like the same setup.  I went through the tutorial twice but my RPI3 is not broadcasting the SSID that I set up.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what issue you're having, but please try my setup from https://github.com/avishayp/pi-ap. I've tested it with multiple rpi3 devices.